“one can find a set with cardinality n” or “one can find a set of cardinality n” -- using cardinality as an adjective
A set S is a mathematical object. We call the number of objects contained in S the cardinality of S, that is, the cardinality, colloquially, is the size of the set S.
In mathematics texts, I've seen authors use both (incorrectly?). Which would be more appropriate?

Welcome to ELUI stack exchange. Please note that your question needs to contain the actual question - it is not clear what you are asking if part of the question is only contained in the title. FWIW I don't believe the quotations in the title use the word "cardinality" as an adjective. Please explain why you think this is an adjectival use of the word.

"Cardinalty" is not an adjective in this context; there is no doubt about that.

I think "cardinality" is an adjective in this context, it is a technical term used in mathematics, it is a quantitative property of sets, which are mathematical objects. I think it is incorrect to downvote this question

@User559 'I think "cardinality" is an adjective in this context' – What makes you say that? I would say it's obviously a noun here.

In neither of your title's examples is cardinality functioning as an adjective. Ask yourself, "What noun phrase would cardinality be modifying, either in set with cardinality n or in set of cardinality n?"

Neither one of the two propositions is "more appropriate" than the other; both are correct in this context, but the preposition "of" is used much more often; in other words it is much preferred by mathematical writers.


@Lambie Your correction is perhaps more elegant, but "there is not one of them", "there is not one of you", etc. are correct constructions (maybe, there are particular contexts where those take on added connotatons, but I am at a loss for precisions).

"There is not one of them" is not great for two choices. There is not one of them who knows how to swim. [of a group of people]. I'm right, you're wrong here. Just accept it. :)
